# Controlling type application order in poly-kinded typeclasses

Tags: haskell

I'm using GHC 8.4.2. I have this typeclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeApplications #-}
import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Proxy

class Foo (a :: k) where
    foo :: Proxy a -> Int

instance Foo True where
    foo _ = 0

instance Foo Char where
    foo _ = 0
```

It's a much simplified version of the real case, which needs to be poly-kinded.

When I try to use `TypeApplications` with the `foo` method, turns out that I need to specify the kind `k` as the first type parameter, otherwise it won't work:

```
ghci> :t foo @Type @Char
foo @Type @Char :: Proxy Char -> Int

ghci> :t foo @Bool @True
foo @Bool @True :: Proxy 'True -> Int
```

Having to specify the kind as the first type parameter is quite annoying for my real use-case. The kind is determined by the second type parameter anyway.

Is there a way of not having to supply the kind first, or even of not having to supply it at all, while still remaining poly-kinded?

Additionally, is there a way of knowing the correct order of type applications for a class method, when using ghci?

**Edit.** The extra argument disappears when I don't explicitly name the kind, for example:

```
class Foo (a :: k) where
    foo :: Proxy a -> Int

*Main> :set -fprint-explicit-foralls
*Main> :t +v foo
foo :: forall k (a :: k). Foo a => Proxy a -> Int

class Foo a where
    foo :: Proxy a -> Int

*Main> :set -fprint-explicit-foralls
*Main> :t +v foo
foo :: forall {k} (a :: k). Foo a => Proxy a -> Int
```

In this last version we only need to provide a single type argument. `{k}` seems to mean that the kind is inferred.

Alas, I need to name the kind because in my real signatures I need to say "this type has the same kind as this other type, whatever that is".

Comment: What about `foo (Proxy @Char)` and `foo (Proxy @'True)`? There `k` should be inferred correctly. I don't think there's a way to leave some type arguments inplicit and some explicit in functions like we can instead do for constructors (like `Proxy`, which is polykinded but leaves `k` implicit, AFAICS). In Coq/Agda the implicit/explicit stuff can be controlled more easily, but in Haskell we don't have the same tools.

Comment: @chi That would work, but make my actual API more cumbersome to use. I have invocations like `insertI @"name" 5`.

Comment: Due to GHC Proposal #26: "Explicit Specificity", you should be able to write `class Foo (a :: k) where { foo' :: Int }; foo :: forall {k :: Type} (a :: k). Foo a => Int; foo = foo' @k @a` at some point in the future. Not making this an answer as it doesn't work in current GHC Haskell. Fun fact, the signature of `foo` looks uncannily like the one given as an example in the [proposal itself](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0026-explicit-specificity.rst).

Answer (score 3):

You can write `@_` and let GHC infer the kind argument: `foo @_ @True Proxy`

I believe the order of type applications is always the order that type variables appear in the output of `:t`.

For example, `:t foo` gives `foo :: forall k (a :: k). Foo a => Proxy a -> Int`, where `k` appears in the `forall` before the first `a`.

Comment: Thanks. However,  my real use case relies on `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`—type applications are required for all methods. Having to add `@_` to each invocation would greatly hamper usability.